# Get disapproved ads for ad account using FB Marketing API

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api

How to effectively get ids of all disapproved ads for given ad account using Facebook Marketing API?

Ideally it would be something like:

```
GET /act_1231423423423/ads?effective_status=DISAPPROVED&fields=ad_review_feedback
```

but FB does not support such a query

I do not want to fetch all ads, because I have plenty of them.

Comment: _“but FB does not support such a query”_ - according to documentation, it should …? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/ads/#Reading explicitly lists `effective_status` as one of the available filters, so what exactly is not working with this/what error do you get?

Comment: You are right, FB does support it. Filter 'effective_status' needs a list as a value and it was a problem with my query.
The correct is:

     `GET /act_1231423423423/ads?effective_status=["DISAPPROVED"]&fields=ad_review_feedback`

Comment: Ah yeah, the API can be quite picky about the formats (and documentation does not always contain proper examples for such details.) Glad you were able to figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

use

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/ad_account_id/ads?access_token=token&fields=name,id,effective_status&filtering=[{'field':'ad.effective_status' , 'operator':'IN', 'value':['DISAPPROVED']}]
```